# Use WordPress page instead of post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types

Sorry if this is a duplicate – I can't find an answer.

How do I rewrite a custom post type archive page to a 'man-made' WordPress page?

For example:

- Single page: `http://www.mywebsite.com/cool-post-type/awesome-single-post/`
- Archive page: `http://www.mywebsite.com/cool-post-type/`

I want `http://www.mywebsite.com/cool-post-type/` to rewrite to `http://www.mywebsite.com/about-cool-post-types/`.

Can I just do this with htaccess and what would the syntax be? (I'm not good at htaccess!)

This does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^cool-post-type\/\?$ /about-cool-post-types [L]
```

Or do I have to do this in the WordPress source code? I don't want to!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This one's actually pretty easy.  When you declare your post type using [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), you need to add a new argument for 'has_archive'.

So you'll add in something to the effect of:

```
'has_archive' => 'about-cool-post-types'
```

Then, go to your Settings > Permalinks to flush them and it should work.  I tested it locally, and this seems to be the way to automatically generate your archive page at a different URL.  Then, you should be able to create a page at the CPT's slug.

Comment: This stopped working but I managed to fix it by assigning 'has_archive' to arbitrary text and renaming my page's slug to the category slug.

Comment: You could just set `has_archive` to `false` as you don't need the default archive page at all.

Answer (score 8):

There's also a simple, 1-file plugin for this now, by the HumanMade folk;

https://github.com/humanmade/page-for-post-type

(Meta: I know answers with links aren't generally great, but I don't just want to copy and paste the source-code for that thing into an answer. What's the best strategy for this type of thing?)

Comment: This is a pastebin for @RichardsTape answer. A bit late but you never know.
https://pastebin.com/RipbJ64q

Answer (score 1):

Follow up to the accepted answer.

> When you declare your post type using register_post_type, you need to
> add a new argument for 'has_archive'.

What I currently (2023) do is the following:

```
'has_archive' => wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink($page_id))
```

where as the post id I define a ACF options field and get the id for that page like so:

```
'has_archive' => wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink(get_option('archive_page_id','options')))
```

Doing it this way, the page can easyly changed via the wordpress backend.
**Don't forget to re-save the permalinks in order for this to work!**