# Set archive of custom post type like 'posts' page in reading settings is set

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, custom-post-type-archives

I'm starting development on a WordPress site soon. For a specific post type, they want the archive to be part of the page structure.

For the default post type, you can set the archive to a static page, and the parent-child structure of the pages is kept.

Does WordPress offer a way to do this natively, maybe at the registering of the post type? Googling things like 'set custom post type archive to specific page' yields no results. I have not tried anything yet, because I wouldn't know where to start with this and would like to get some information on whether it is even possible within the scope of WordPress. If it is possible, where would I start?

To clarify: Let's say I have a page, `Foo`, it's slug being `/foo`. This page has a child page `Bar`, it's slug thus being `/foo/bar`. I want the archive page of my custom post type to be set at `/foo/bar`, like you could do with the default `post` post type (this would be done via `Settings > Reading`, but that's not important).

I can't write a custom query in a template, because that would not fix the breadcrumbs structure that a plugin like Yoast would display.

Comment: >  _Is it possible to do this for a custom post type, too?_  "Yes." Was it the answer you where waiting for?

Comment: What have you googled and tried already? Please,  show us.

Comment: @MaxYudin I've updated my question, I realise I was kind of unspecific. You could try telling people this in a nicer way, in stead of giving some passive aggressive answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use WordPress page instead of post type archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243373/use-wordpress-page-instead-of-post-type-archive)

Comment: @Connor I agree the comments are a bit cold sometimes. Bear in mind we get a lot of "Please help me put my header 2 pixels down" type questions on here, and questions that have already been asked, so it can get frustrating after a while.

Comment: @Pim This isn't a duplicate. I need the ability to set an archive to a child page of a different page, like you are able to do with the default post type.

Comment: @Pim you are right, I understand that can be frustrating.

Comment: @Connor Then I'm not sure I've understood your question correctly. The above link shows you how to set the archive to a specific page (also child page), instead of displaying the archive template. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Let's see, I might be misunderstanding the answer provided in the other question. I've updated the question again, does this make it more clear?

Comment: In your example, the slug of the child page is `bar`. If you follow the answer in link above and use `bar`as your `has_archive` value, you should get exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I'll report back!

Comment: I've been trying this out, but it does not give the results I hoped it would give. It doesn't set the archive to the child page I've created. So in stead of the archive being at `example.com/foo/bar`, the archive is at `example.com/bar`. I have also tried setting `has_archive` to `foo/bar`, and this seems to work, but it doesn't do everything I hoped it would do. It misses the functionalities the 'posts' archive page has. I don't think what I am trying to achieve is possible within the scope of WordPress.